# how to build and pass objects from snapshots-firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to angular2 and firebase.I am trying to create an object from snapshot value and pass it to another component. Here is my code:
firebase.service.ts

```
getUserProfile(uuid){
  return this.ref.orderByChild("uid")
  .equalTo(uuid)
  .once('value',function(snap){
    var data=snap.val();
    var user = {
      uid:data.uid,
      display_name:data.display_name,
      email:data.email,
      password:data.password,
      tax:data.tax
    }
   return user;
  });
}
```

userprofile.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let uid=this.fb.getUserUid();
    this.fb.getUserProfile(uid).then(function(obj){
      console.log(obj.val());
         console.log(obj.val().display_name);
    })
```

The first console.log prints the value of the object but the second one on which i am trying to get just one value from the object displays 'undefined'.